# Leap Year Calculator not printing any outputs

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
year = int(input("Enter a year: "))
if (year % 4) == 0:
    if (year % 100) == 0 and (year % 400) == 0:
        print (year, "IS a leap year.")
else:
    print (year, "is NOT a leap year.")
```

For some reason, the program doesn't print anything after taking input.

Here's a link for the leap year rules if anyone needs it: https://www.wwu.edu/skywise/leapyear.html

Comment: when I run the code and enter any number, your program prints accordingly....

Comment: You don't have an `else` condition for the second `if`.  So when the number is divisible by 4, but is not divisible by either 100 or 400, the program will do nothing.

Comment: @glls It works for some numbers but it doesn't work for others. So say an input of 2000 prints out stuff but 2008 doesn't :/

Comment: I did this. It works for me for now but I'm not sure how accurate it is or whether I can make the code more efficient. https://gist.github.com/splixer/e0d43707eb23377f0cb40359b0e5b137

Comment: @JohnGordon Oh I got it. yomin explained what you were trying to say. Thanks for the help! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the reason that does not print anything is just as @John Gordon says: miss some **else clauses** in your program. I have modified to the following code:

```
year = int(input("Enter a year: "))
if (year % 4) == 0:
    if (year % 100) == 0 and (year % 400) != 0:
        print (year, "is NOT leap year.")
    else:
        print (year, "is a leap year.")
else:
    print (year, "is NOT a leap year.")
```

When a year can be divided by 4, it may be a leap year. In that sense, when it can be divided by 100 but cannot be divided by 400 ,it is not a leap year. In other situations it is. Simply **you miss some cases** in `year % 4 == 0` situation.

For me, I usually judge leap year in following code:

```
def is_leap_year(year):
    if (year % 4 == 0 and year % 100 != 0) or year % 400 == 0:
        return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my program taken from "The C Programming Language 2nd Edition":

```
year = int(input("Enter a year: "))
if year % 4 == 0 and year % 100 != 0 or year % 400 == 0:
    print "Leap year"
else:
    print "Not leap"
```

I think the rules provided on the link you mentioned are wrong. A leap year should be divisible by 4 and must *not* be divisible by 100. However, if it is divisible by 100 but also divisible by 400, it *is* leap.